# Java stream trim list

Tags: java, java-stream, trim

I have the following implementation for trimming a list of elements based on a given predicate (that is - remove leading and trailing empty elements).

I would like to make the implementation more readable, preferably using Java's stream API's.

```
/**
 * Trim a List based on a given predicate, that is, remove leading
 * and trailing elements that match the predicate (but not in-between
 * non-matching elements).
 *
 * @param list the list to trim
 * @param trimPredicate the predicate for trimming
 * @param <T> type of the list
 * @return the same list minus the trimmed elements.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the list is {@code null}
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the {@code remove}
 *      operation is not supported by the list iterator
 */
public static <T> List<T> trim(List<T> list, Predicate<T> trimPredicate)
        throws NullPointerException, UnsupportedOperationException {
    if (list == null) throw new NullPointerException("list is null");
    ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator();
    while (it.hasNext() && trimPredicate.test(it.next())) it.remove();
    it = list.listIterator(list.size());
    while (it.hasPrevious() && trimPredicate.test(it.previous())) it.remove();

    return list;
}
```

Any suggestions?

An example, to make things clearer:

For `List<Integer>`, considering `0` to be an empty value, the following list:

```
[0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 4, 0, -3, 0, 0]
```

Will be trimmed to:

```
[3, 5, 0, 4, 0, -3]
```

(And the fact that at least two different readers here got it wrong, demonstrates my point regarding the code's readability :).

Comment: how about filtering non-empty ones? i mean its fairly basic - did you do any research ?

Comment: Filtering operations are stateless AFAIK, so I can't filter based on location in the list.

Comment: Then you want to remove the first and the last elements from the list if those are empty right?

Comment: Thats what I meant by "remove leading and trailing empty elements"

Comment: What about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: @LazerBanana `removeIf` also does not provide stateful operations out of the box... What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your original code is pretty readable and efficient. recommended.

```
static <T> List<T> trim2(List<T> list, Predicate<T> isEmpty) {
    ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator();
    while (it.hasNext() && isEmpty.test(it.next())) {
        it.remove();
    }
    it = list.listIterator(list.size());
    while (it.hasPrevious() && isEmpty.test(it.previous())) {
        it.remove();
    }
    return list;
}
```

stream version using java 9. just for the heck of it, not recommended.

```
static <T> List<T> trim3(List<T> list, Predicate<T> isEmpty) {
    Collection<T> ltrimreverse = list.stream().dropWhile(isEmpty)
        .collect(ArrayDeque::new, ArrayDeque::push, ArrayDeque::addAll);
    Collection<T> rtrim = ltrimreverse.stream().dropWhile(isEmpty)
        .collect(ArrayDeque::new, ArrayDeque::push, ArrayDeque::addAll);
    return new ArrayList<>(rtrim);
}
```

Comment: I've edited my code to one-liner iteration loops. Thanks for the Java 9 insight.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of hackery makes it possible, but I am not sure it is any clearer.

```
/**
 * Stateful predicate to only match until matching fails.
 * It seems this is not necessary in Java 9.
 */
static class MatchWhile<T> implements Predicate<T> {
    final Predicate<T> matcher;
    boolean match = true;

    MatchWhile(Predicate<T> matcher) {
        this.matcher = matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(T t) {
        return match && (match = matcher.test(t));
    }
}

// Hides the horrible stuff.
static <T> Stream<T> asStream(Iterator<T> it) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it,Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
}

<T> List<T> trim2(List<T> list, Predicate<T> isEmpty) {
    // Trim right using a Deque to reverse it.
    Deque<T> reversedAndTrimmedAtEnd = asStream(new ArrayDeque<>(list).descendingIterator())
            .filter(new MatchWhile<>(isEmpty).negate())
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));
    // Reverse it again to trim left.
    List<T> leftTrimmed = asStream(reversedAndTrimmedAtEnd.descendingIterator())
            .filter(new MatchWhile<>(isEmpty).negate())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return leftTrimmed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you care for efficiency, you should avoid repeated single `remove` operations, especially at the beginning of the `List`, as the most commonly used implementation, `ArrayList`, does not perform very well at this, as it has to copy all remaining elements within its internal array when you remove an entry.

The worst case, i.e. removing all elements this way, would have a quadratic time complexity.

```
public static <T> List<T> trim(List<T> list, Predicate<T> trimPredicate) {

    Objects.requireNonNull(list, "list is null");
    Objects.requireNonNull(trimPredicate, "trimPredicate is null");

    int lastMatch;

    for(ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator(lastMatch = list.size());
        it.hasPrevious() && trimPredicate.test(it.previous());) lastMatch = it.nextIndex();

    if(lastMatch < list.size()) list.subList(lastMatch, list.size()).clear();

    for(ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator(lastMatch = 0);
        it.hasNext() && trimPredicate.test(it.next()); ) lastMatch = it.previousIndex();

    if(lastMatch > 0) list.subList(0, lastMatch+1).clear();

    return list;
}
```

`List.subList(…).clear()` is the correct idiom for removing a range of items efficiently. In case of `ArrayList`, it implies only a single copy operation for the entire range removal. So we only iterate without removing, to identify the range, then perform a single removal operation.

Since removing at the end has no additional costs, as there are no remaining elements to copy, this solution first removes the matches at the end, to potentially reduce the number of remaining elements for the subsequent removal of the matches at the front of the list.

For an in-place operation, which will modify the list directly, there is no Stream solution that would improve it.

Even when you want to return a new list, one of the most efficient solutions would be based on `subList`:

```
public static <T> List<T> trim(List<T> list, Predicate<T> trimPredicate) {

    Objects.requireNonNull(list, "list is null");
    Objects.requireNonNull(trimPredicate, "trimPredicate is null");

    int firstToKeep = 0, lastToKeep = list.size();
    for(T t: list) if(trimPredicate.test(t)) firstToKeep++; else break;
    for(ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator(lastToKeep);
        lastToKeep > firstToKeep && it.hasPrevious() && trimPredicate.test(it.previous());)
        lastToKeep = it.nextIndex();

    return new ArrayList<>(list.subList(firstToKeep, lastToKeep));
}
```